# VisualStudio 2017 - can't add resx file

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, resx

I'm trying to setup localization in my xamarin.form application following this tutorial : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/ .

But when I go to the menu 'add new item' in vs 2017 I can't find a option to create a resource file. Why is that? what is the solution?

[image: no resx file]

Comment: Are you writing directly in the search box? Have you tried clicking on the General tab?

Answer (score 1):

By writing the word `resx` in the search box you will not be able to find the template for resource files. You must click on the General tab and locate in the resource files option.

If this does not work you should [repair Visual Studio](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37492.modify-repair-and-uninstall-visual-studio-2017-using-visual-studio-installer.aspx) from the Visual Studio installer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm going to switch to RIder IDE I'm sick of visual studio.

Comment: I've the same problem. Repairing didn't fix it. Only "Resource Dictionary" and "Resources File (.resw)" are available as templates.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had to modified my installation and check **.NET desktop development**

That solved my problem

[image: .NET desktop development]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this was resolved in VS2017 
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/85616/add-new-item-resource-file-resx-missing.html
but I had to use the same fix to get it working in VS2019